# Is it possible to customize deprecated language features in VSCode?

Tags: angular, vue.js, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

In VSCode, Vue devs will see the `align` keyword highlighted in red in HTML templates. The `align` keyword is deprecated in plain HTML, but is a valid attribute in Vue, Angular and other frameworks. Here is an example:

[image: Example: Vue template]

Is there any way to instruct VSCode to override this settings?

Note: This question was [asked before](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66723) in GitHub but was closed automatically.

Comment: not a real solution but have you thought about changing your theme...?

Comment: Some deprecated HTML is also useful in Markdown for when you're, say, displaying Markdown on GitHub, you have no control over their Markdown stylesheet, and the CSS styling you'd rather use get stripped out and ignored.